# date to display the EDT time

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to check the time

> Eastern Daylight Time
>   Time zone in Washington, DC, USA (GMT-4)
>   Thursday, May 9, 2019, 8:11 PM

However,

```
$ TZ="EDT" date
Fri May 10 00:12:25 EDT 2019
```

"EST" works properly

```
$ TZ="EST" date
Thu May  9 19:13:11 EST 2019
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`date` command doesn't know "EDT" timezone. If a timezone which isn't supported is passed in TZ the output will indeed show with entered time zone but time shown will be UTC.

Supported time zones are listed in ***/usr/share/zoneinfo/***. As of now time zones that can be used as a value for "TZ" are:

```
Africa      Cuba     GMT0         Japan              Pacific     Turkey
America     EET      GMT-0        Kwajalein          Poland      UCT
Antarctica  Egypt    GMT+0        leap-seconds.list  Portugal    Universal
Arctic      Eire     Greenwich    Libya              posix       US
Asia        EST      Hongkong     localtime          posixrules  UTC
Atlantic    EST5EDT  HST          MET                PRC         WET
Australia   Etc      Iceland      Mexico             PST8PDT     W-SU
Brazil      Europe   Indian       MST                right       zone1970.tab
Canada      Factory  Iran         MST7MDT            ROC         zone.tab
CET         GB       iso3166.tab  Navajo             ROK         Zulu
Chile       GB-Eire  Israel       NZ                 Singapore
CST6CDT     GMT      Jamaica      NZ-CHAT            SystemV
```

The time zone for EDT is "EST5EDT". The output of `TZ="EST5EDT" date` as of 10 May 2019 02:11:26 UTC:

```
Thu May  9 22:11:26 EDT 2019
```

Or use city's name where EDT is used. Examples: America/Kentucky/Louisville, America/Kentucky/Monticello, America/New_York, Canada/Eastern, etc.

#### Why EDT is EST5EDT?

In short, it is a standard. Time zones are written like ***Timezone-Offset***. Here **-** is minus or it can be said for time zones which are ahead of UTC are written like ***Timezone-Offset*** and for time zones that are behind UTC, it is written as ***TimezoneOffset***. If the time zone has a pretty name like Eastern Standard Time, it can be written as **EST** or **EST5**. Both will produce same results.

Now, Daylight Saving Time (DST) isn't observed everywhere (for example, India). For time zones where it is observed, time zones are written as ***Timezone-OffsetTimezoneDST***, example: ***EET-2EETDST*** (Cyprus) but if DST has a fancy name like BST (British Summer Time), it is written as ***Timezone-OffsetFancy_name***, i.e. ***GMT0BST***. Similary, ***EDT*** is ***EST5EDT***. On [this Oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25553_01/calendar.1012/b25486/time_zones.htm) you can see all standardized time zones.

Answer (score 11):

`EDT` is ambiguous when considered internationally.  You can get the time you are seeking by doing

```
$ TZ="America/New_York" date
Thu May  9 22:11:16 EDT 2019
```