# Time is behind by an hour even though TZ is correctly set

Tags: 18.04, time, timezone

I have an Ubuntu 18 server VM running in ESXI.  The timezone is set correctly but the time is still behind by an hour.

```
root@devserver:~# timedatectl
                      Local time: Thu 2020-03-19 12:20:30 EST
                  Universal time: Thu 2020-03-19 17:20:30 UTC
                        RTC time: Thu 2020-03-19 17:20:30
                       Time zone: EST (EST, -0500)
       System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

The time should be 13:21. Do I need to do make some kind of DST setting?  It should be -0400, not 0500.

Comment: You need to switch to EDT a.k.a EST5EDT instead of EST.

Comment: that did the trick thanks! if you put it in an answer i can mark it correct

Comment: I'm not sure if this deserves a separate answer since your questions seems more like a combination of [Setting timezone from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/323131/816190) and [date to display the EDT time](https://askubuntu.com/q/1141967/816190)