# 'date' Command Failure in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, date

I am getting errors on the `date` command if I use the timezone designation stored in the system:

```
$ date -d "2019-12-10 23:26:30 EDT +4 hours"
date: invalid date ‘2019-12-10 23:26:30 EDT +4 hours’
```

```
$ date -d "2019-12-10 23:26:30 EST +4 hours"
Wed Dec 11 03:26:30 EST 2019
```

Here's what I get when I ask to display the time zone information:

```
$ date +"%Z %z"
EDT -0400
```

Is this an error on my part or has something changed in the system?

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS x86_64 with kernel 5.7.1-050701-generic.

Comment: No.  date -d "2019-12-10 23:26:30 EST5EDT +4 hours"
date: invalid date ‘2019-12-10 23:26:30 EST5EDT +4 hours’

Comment: Reviewers: Note, the above comment is in regard to the previous duplicate closure to [date to display the EDT time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141967/date-to-display-the-edt-time). So this shouldn't be reclosed as a duplicate of that, at least not without explanation.